# How do you vertically align the titles of two different buttons with different title sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The follow button next to the user's name seems to be vertically centered whereas I want to align the baselines of both titles.

I'm looking to align this programmatically.

[image: Reveal inspection of the two button titles]

Comment: Can you be more clear? Are you trying to align the text on the buttons or are you trying to align the buttons themselves? Are you trying to align them on the bottom? And what is the Asdfasdf? It would also be nice if you could post some code :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to align the text (title) on the buttons themselves.  It looks like the Follow button title is centered vertically rather than aligned to the bottom.

Comment: @ben:just check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you don't have fixed width and height both of your label and button.

Then your code will look like this.Just to mention i am using LayoutAnchor as it's easy.

```
func autolayoutTitle() {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = "Nafeez Zawahir"
    label.textAlignment = .right
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
   // label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

    let button = UIButton()
    //button.titleLabel?.text = "Follow"
    button.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   // button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
   // button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.rightAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true


    button.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
   // button.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.lastBaselineAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true


}
```

And the output is:

[image]

But if you have fixed **width** and **height** of your label as well as your button too, then you have to tune your **button's baseline anchoring** with **label's baseline anchor** which depends on **label's height.**

Let's say you have label's height 40 like this.

```
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Then your button's baseline anchoring should be like this.

```
button.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.lastBaselineAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Below is the code:

```
func autolayoutTitle() {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.text = "Nafeez Zawahir"
        label.textAlignment = .right
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

        let button = UIButton()
        //button.titleLabel?.text = "Follow"
        button.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.rightAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true


       // button.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.lastBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
        button.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.lastBaselineAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true


    }
```

And this is the output:

[image]